# Al abrir un Excel desde MS Access para exportar me convierte el archivo Excel en Readonly

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

tengo el problema de la pregunta, desde MS Access uso Excel para importar y exportar información usando:

La hoja destino en cuestión tiene una hoja con casi todas sus celdas protegidas (se desconoce la clave) aunque la exportación se hace en una hoja distinta.

Alguien sabrá por qué esta hoja se transforma en readonly, o es que me falta algo en el código?
Agradeceré cualquier ayuda o idea `introducir el código aquí`al respecto.

```
On Error GoTo ErreXP
Screen.MousePointer = 11 'PathE = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\finalThanos.xlsx"
Set WBExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
WBExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open (PathE)
WBExcel.Windows(fname).Activate
WBExcel.sheets("Month").Select
```

Comment: que error te da al poner el codigo? sera muchisimo codigo?

Comment: On Error GoTo ErreXP
    Screen.MousePointer = 11
    'PathE = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\finalThanos.xlsx"
    Set WBExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    WBExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open (PathE)
    WBExcel.Windows(fname).Activate
    WBExcel.sheets("Month").Select

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade la información ahí, no la pongas como comentario, porque se hace difícil de leer.

Comment: EL problema es que al agregar el codigo la página me dice que el mismo no cumple las normas de identación y por más que uso el simbolo de ajuste al codigo o lo hago manual me sigue dando error y no me deja publicar

Comment: ya te hicieron el paro de editarla, solo queda esperar a que acepten la edición. Saludos.

Comment: En tu ejemplo estás intentando abrir un libro en una ruta que has comentado (PathE) y no lo va a localizar.
De todas formas, ¿estás seguro que es la hoja la que está como readonly?Para evitar que el libro se abra como readonly añade el parámetro ReadOnly:=false. Si el autor, por defecto, ha guardado el libro como solo lectura te preguntará antes si deseas abrirlo así o en modo edición. Para que no pregunte utiliza el parámetro IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True en el procedimiento workbools.open: WBExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathE, ReadOnly:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a los compañeros preocupados, halle el problema, no estaba cerrando Excel, ya que el .close me daba error y lo había eliminado y lo sustituí por:

```
WBExcel.WINDOWS(xlsxFile).Close savechanges:=True
```

Ese era el problema, al no cerrarlo quedaba en el limbo y permanecia enlazado a Excel sin cerrarse. Si lo trataba de abrir luego me indicaba que era readonl y así permanecía hasta reiniciar el pc, aunque quedaba readonly.